# Angular 11 set first option selected

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried many things but didnt work.
how can i  set first option of the data comes from Api. It chooses last option

```
  <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!hideItem">
            <p></p>
            <select
              class="form-select"
              type="option"
              id="optionFour"
              formControlName="optionFour"
            >
              <option *ngFor="let option of lvlThreeOptions" [value]="option.id"
              [selected]="lvlThreeOptions[0]">
                {{ option.name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: `<option *ngFor="let option of lvlThreeOptions; first as first" [value]="option.id"
              [selected]="first">` [see here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="lvlThreeOptions?.length > 0">
        <p></p>
        <select
          [(ngModel)]="selectedLvlThree"
          class="form-select"
          type="option"
          id="optionFour"
          formControlName="optionFour"
        >
          <option *ngFor="let option of lvlThreeOptions" [value]="option.id">
            {{ option.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
                                                                 option.component.html
                                                                       
                                                           



this.optionService
      .getOptionsById(this.selectedLvlTwo, 1)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.lvlThreeOptions = response.data;
        console.log(this.lvlThreeOptions);
         this.selectedLvlThree = this.lvlThreeOptions[0].id;
     
      });
                                                                   option.component.ts
```

that solved my problem